# Obtener datos de Isar para llenar List y despues llamar a la lilsta

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

Estoy utilizando Providers de Riverpod para obtener datos de Isar y llenar una lista y si llena la lista, el problema esta que a la hora que llamo la lista de Riverpod la lista esta vacía. Les comparto el código que tengo hasta este momento.

> Vista

```
class _CardsView extends ConsumerWidget {
  final int idTecnico;
  final String poliza;

  const _CardsView({required this.idTecnico, required this.poliza});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final providerSiniestro = ref.read(siniestroProvider);

    providerSiniestro.getIncisosSiniestroList(idTecnico, poliza);
    List<Siniestro> listSiniestros =  providerSiniestro.incisosSiniestroList;

    print("LISTADO DE SINIESTROS");
    print(listSiniestros);

    return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: providerSiniestro.incisosSiniestroList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final inciso = providerSiniestro.incisosSiniestroList[index];

        return _CardType1(dataInciso: inciso);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

> Provider Riverpod

```
final isDeviceConnected = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);

class ConnectionSiniestroNotifier {

  List<Siniestro> _incisosSiniestroList = [];

  List<Siniestro> get incisosSiniestroList => _incisosSiniestroList;

  Future<void> getIncisosSiniestroList(int idTecnico, String poliza) async {
    _incisosSiniestroList = [];

    if (isDeviceConnected.value) {

      _incisosSiniestroList = await IsarHelperSiniestro.instance.getInicisosSiniestro(idTecnico, poliza);
    }
  }
}

final siniestroProvider = Provider((ref) => ConnectionSiniestroNotifier());
```

Cuando lleno _incisosSiniestroList de Riverpod, pero cuando lo llamo en la vista esta vacio.

¿Saben que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Espero que me puedan apoyar.
Saludos!